# Ask SMTP Server for Delivery Status Notification

Tags: smtp, dsn

I would like to know if this is possible to ask a SMTP Server if it received a specific email even if I'm not the server who sends the email ?

for instance, user a@sender.com is sending an email to b@receiver.com, then I have an independent server who is asking SMTP Server receiver.com if this email has been received (using Message-ID header value for instance)

I've seen that most of SMTP Servers are implementing DSN, but I don't know if it can be asked by anybody....

Answer (score 0):

As a third party, not either the sender nor recipient of the message, nothing in SMTP provides any way for a third party to find out the status or even existence of any message. That would be a horrible privacy violation, or worse.

Comment: ok I understand. Only "sender" MTA Server is able to ask for DSN right ?

Comment: @tiamat That is correct. Only the sender can request a DSN. And it must be done at the same time the mail is sent. You can read RFC 3461 to see how it works in depth.